Visual Studio 2022 - cannot find ts module after update
I have a project in angular that I just updated from v14 to v17.
After the update everything compiles and builds, but opening ts files in editor show a lot of "Cannot find module":

I guess there's something wrong with intellisense or typescript, but I can't figure out what.
This is my tsconfig.json:
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "declaration": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2020",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "es2020",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2020",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}


change  "baseUrl"to src in your tsconfig.json and restart VS and see if this is due to VS failed to resolve project root and see if it can work.

@AmadeuszLiu didn't worked.

You could try to delete Node Modules folder and then run "npm cache clean --force" and "npm install" and reboot your computer and check if this can work.

It found out that Visual Studio ignore the tsconfig.json.
I had to add in the .csproj:
true
4.8.4
true
